# Permanently enabling macros for ONE Excel file

Tags: excel, security

Using Windows XP and Excel 2007

I have a worksheet with a macro in it saved to the computer. There is a shortcut to it on the desktop. Every time I open it the macro is disabled "to protect my security". Is there a way I can enable macros for the file every time? Ideally w/out disabling this security feature for other files (eg ones downloaded or whatever).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [certify your own projects](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/digitally-sign-a-macro-project-HA001231781.aspx#BM2)  to a certain extent.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like what I was looking for.